# General Topology with Categorical Mindset

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, soft-question

I am currently self-leaning general topology following *Topology* written by Munkres, and I have a basic sense of category theory after finishing reading *Algebra: Chapter 0* written by Paolo Aluffi. I hold the idea that some category theory would make arguments in general topology much more elegant, [and here is one example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817901/depiction-of-convergence-in-categorical-sense) It should also be clearer to state which spaces make up a category, and which categories are complete, etc etc.

So, is my comprehension correct, and are there any textbooks, papers, etc that approaches general topology in a categorical mindset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned Bradley, Bryson, and Terilla's [Topology: A Categorical Approach](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262539357/topology/). The description sounds like exactly what you're looking for:

> This graduate-level textbook on topology takes a unique approach: it reintroduces basic, point-set topology from a more modern, categorical perspective. Many graduate students are familiar with the ideas of point-set topology and they are ready to learn something new about them. Teaching the subject using category theory—a contemporary branch of mathematics that provides a way to represent abstract concepts—both deepens students' understanding of elementary topology and lays a solid foundation for future work in advanced topics.
>
> After presenting the basics of both category theory and topology, the book covers the universal properties of familiar constructions and three main topological properties—connectedness, Hausdorff, and compactness. It presents a fine-grained approach to convergence of sequences and filters; explores categorical limits and colimits, with examples; looks in detail at adjunctions in topology, particularly in mapping spaces; and examines additional adjunctions, presenting ideas from homotopy theory, the fundamental groupoid, and the Seifert van Kampen theorem. End-of-chapter exercises allow students to apply what they have learned. The book expertly guides students of topology through the important transition from undergraduate student with a solid background in analysis or point-set topology to graduate student preparing to work on contemporary problems in mathematics.

The authors have made a free html version of the book available [here](https://topology.mitpress.mit.edu/) (just click on the chapter titles to get the pdfs of each chapter).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 3):

As far as books covering topology, *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John M. Lee ([here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441979395)) approaches a lot of concepts categorically. These include universal properties of basic topological spaces and some groups (quotient, subspace, product,
and disjoint union topological spaces, as well as free products, free groups, free abelian groups); definitions of objects, morphisms, categories, and functors; coproducts and products; and chain complexes and cochain complexes. While the primary focus is not on teaching topology categorically, the approach is very categorical in nature.

*Categories for the Working Mathematician* by Saunders Mac Lane ([here](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/%7Eebatista/2016-2/maclanecat.pdf)) goes over a lot of examples in category theory. Many of these involve categories related to topological spaces. My personal favorite is the construction of the fundamental group using the groupoid $\pi(X)$. I will warn you this book is very dense (albeit thorough), and I highly advise working through most/all of Lee before diving into the purely categorical setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the book [Abstract and Concrete Categories - The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) since it covers many examples from general topology. It is not a text primarily about topology, though.

Answer (score 1):

Although it probably skews more towards algebraic topology than general topology, the book [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) by Ronald Brown may be a good option.